# MSBuild unable to find metadata file for PresentationCore

Tags: msbuild

I am writing a MSBuild file for one of my .NET projects. I do not want to use the Visual Studio generated .sln and .csproj files for certain reasons. I am also aiming to get some experience writing my own build files.

One of my source files is referencing the System.Windows.Media namespace and the build failed with the below message

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Media' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

So I added the following snippet in my build file...

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore">
        <RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

I made changes in the CSC task as follows...

```
<Target Name="ReleaseBuild">
        <MakeDir Directories="$(ReleaseDir)"/>
        <Csc    Sources="@(SrcFile)"
                OutputAssembly="$(ReleaseDir)\$(OutputAssemblyName)"
                TargetType="Library"
                References="@(Reference);
                            $(LibDir)\MyOwnLib.DLL"
                Platform="$(ProcessorPlatform)">
        </Csc>
</Target>
```

only to get the following error -   `CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'PresentationCore' could not be found`

Why is MSBuild not able to find the PresentationCore assembly in the GAC? Is there some additional version information that I should give? I searched in many forums but seem to be going around in circles and I would be glad for any useful pointers as to what the problem could be.

I am using MSBuild 4.0 on an x64 machine and building for an x86 target. My build files which referenced only the MS core libraries worked fine. My VS2008 projects also build fine.

***Some Progress***

I was able to progress in this issue by making the following changes...

1) I added a property to specify the path of the presentation core library - `<PresentationCoreLibDir>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35</PresentationCoreLibDir>`

2) Added an additional parameter to the CSC task like this - `AdditionalLibPaths="$(PresentationCoreLibDir)"`

3) Finally appended the **.DLL** suffix to the reference tag -
`<ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="PresentationCore.DLL">
            <RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
        </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>`

I am relieved that I was able to get around this, but is there a neater way of doing this? I thought that the MSBuild engine would be able to figure this out in a more seamless way. Can anyone throw more light on this?

Comment: What happens if you remove `<RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>`?

Comment: I removed it and there was no change. It still complains of the same error.

Answer (score 2):

For x86 make sure you use the correct MSBuild which should be at:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
```

Rather than the x64 MSBuild that is located at:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
```

Comment: I have used the correct x32 MSBuild located at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319, so that is okay. Thanks for the reminder.